# Remove blank rows when print

Tags: excel, vba

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NiQWC.png) im getting this error when using your code

```
Dim answer As Integer

answer = MsgBox("Äðóêóâàòè?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Äðóê")
If answer = vbYes Then
ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = "A1:N27"
ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintOut
Else
'End
End If

End Sub
```

need the macro to print areas that are field within range A1:N27 and delete blank can someone solve it? [image: form that I am filing]

Due to my fault there where three problems that FaneDuru has found with my workbook that his code didn't worked with my workbook

1. The rows to be hide/deleted are not empty. They contains formulas...
2. The result of formula on column D:D is "".
3. The worksheet in discussion is protected, but without a password

Comment: Do you consider blank rows the one not being blank in column M:M?

Comment: yes, can you help me implement your code in to mine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the next code, please. It will hide the rows being empty on the range B:L, print and then un-hide them. The updated code is done according to your last specifications (there are formulas in the 'empty' rows, in column D:D the formula result is "" and the worksheet is protected, but without a password):

```
Sub testRemoveRowsPrintAreaSet()
 Dim sh As Worksheet, lastRow As Long, rngDel As Range, i As Long
 
 Set sh = ActiveSheet
 lastRow = sh.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
 
 For i = 9 To lastRow
 Debug.Print WorksheetFunction.CountBlank(sh.Range("B" & i & ":L" & i))
    If WorksheetFunction.CountBlank(sh.Range("B" & i & ":L" & i)) = 10 Then
       If rngDel Is Nothing Then
            Set rngDel = sh.Range("M" & i)
       Else
            Set rngDel = Union(rngDel, sh.Range("M" & i))
       End If
    End If
 Next i
 If Not rngDel Is Nothing Then
    sh.Unprotect
    rngDel.EntireRow.Hidden = True
 End If
 sh.PageSetup.PrintArea = "A1:N" & lastRow
 ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintOut
 rngDel.EntireRow.Hidden = False
 sh.Protect
End Sub
```

Please, confirm that it work as you need.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion or debugging sessions; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218870/discussion-on-answer-by-faneduru-remove-blank-rows-when-print). If you have a follow-up question, please ask a new question.

Comment: works like a charm now, sorry for me not specifying the problem correctly

Comment: @Vova Panchyshyn: Glad I could help! But I hop you also learned something: A question can be better answered if it is very well formulated. And vice versa... :)